# Flac player stops when other sounds play

Tags: 14.04, music, flac, gmusicbrowser

I have a question about my music player in Ubuntu 14.04

I'm using gmusicbrowser 1.1.14 with a flac plug-in to play flac (flac123 0.0.11). It doesn't matter which song I play, they all have the same problem. The song is playing correct, but every time I get a chat message or something else (when there is a sound playing), the music is muted (the player continues playing, but there's no sound any more).

It's only when playing high quality flac (mp3 is working fine), could it be some setting in the gmusicbrowser, or maybe some bandwidth limitation from my sound card? Or maybe I should try some other plug-ins, don't know if there are any for flac playback.

What can I do to debug / fix this?

Thanks in advance!